# How to use environmenty specific .env file with firebase deploy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have my 3 projects on my local emulator and

```
.env.myfirebaseproject-dev
.env.myfirebaseproject-prod
```

How can i specify which one is used when i run

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

Comment: You can't specify anything on the command line.  The CLI uses files it finds based on the current project.  See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#deploying_multiple_sets_of_environment_variables) for details.

Comment: Its ok yes but you can not specify a folder where you want you .env to be. They must be in functions folder root of your project

Comment: Yes, that's pretty standard for the way .env files normally work in projects.  That's not unique to Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

```
.env
.env.local 
.env.<your-project-name>
```

All will be deployed and ones with the firebase project name will be used when deployed.

I would like give that instruction to the firebase deploy to exclude other files from deployment but it is what it is